# replace a unknown string between two known strings with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file with the following contents:

`WORD1 WORD2 WORD3`

How can I use sed to replace the string between WORD1 and WORD3 with `foo`, such that the contents of the file are changed to the following?:

`WORD1 foo WORD3`

I tried the following, but obviously I'm missing something because that does not produce the desired results:

`sed -i '' 's/WORD1.*WORD3/foo/g' file.txt`

Comment: Could there be something like `WORD1 foo WORD3 bar WORD1 baz WORD3` in your string (i. e. more than one match per string)?

Comment: Ah - good question, but no, it's not really necessary to accommodate for more than one match in this scenario.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/WORD1.*WORD3/WORD1 foo WORD3/g' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -i 's/(WORD1).*(WORD3)/\1 foo \2/g' file.txt
```

You might need to escape round brackets, depends on your sed variant.

Comment: what should I do to allow WORD1, WORD2 and WORD3 be any strings?

Comment: @ValeriyVan, you need to escape delimiting chars in your WORDs (`/` in my example) as well as all other chars, that `sed` treats as controlling ones.

Comment: The second option results in: `sed: -e expression #1, char 30: invalid reference \2 on 's' command's RHS` on GNU bash, version 4.4.19

Comment: @user3751385 escape the `(` and `)`

Comment: @user3751385 or add `-r`

Answer (score 7):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\S\+/foo/2' file
```

or perhaps:

```
sed 's/[^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*/foo/2' file
```

If `WORD1` and `WORD3` occur more than once:

```
echo "WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 BLA BLA WORD1 WORD4 WORD3" |
sed 's/WORD3/\n&/g;s/\(WORD1\)[^\n]*\n/\1 foo /g'
WORD1 foo WORD3 BLA BLA WORD1 foo WORD3
```

Comment: `[^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*` can be replaced by `[^[:space:]]\+` (as you have used in your first example) in some versions of `sed`. The `/2` is a nice touch. +1

Answer (score 3):

content of a sample `file.txt`

```
$ cat file.txt 
WORD1 WORD2 WORD3
WORD4 WORD5 WORD6
WORD7 WORD8 WORD9
```

(Correction by [@DennisWilliamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) in comment)
`$ sed -e 's/\([^ ]\+\) \+\([^ ]\+\) \+\(.*\)/\1 foo \3/' file.txt`

```
WORD1 foo WORD3
WORD4 foo WORD6
WORD7 foo WORD9
```

while `awk` is somehow simpler

`$ awk -F' ' '{ print $1" foo "$3 }' file.txt`

```
WORD1 foo WORD3
WORD4 foo WORD6
WORD7 foo WORD9
```

Comment: It's not necessary to escape any of the spaces. And `[^\ ]` means "any character other than space or backslash. I would suggest `\+` instead of `*` since, as is, your command could replace an empty line. Also `g` is unnecessary - as is the redirection.

Comment: Now it won't work at all. You misunderstood what I meant. `sed -e 's/\([^ ]\+\) \+\([^ ]\+\) \+\(.*\)/\1 foo \3/' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to the initial question is:

Linux (GNU sed):

`sed -i '/WORD1/, /WORD3/ s/WORD2/foo/' file.txt`

MacOS (UNIX sed):

`sed -i '' '/WORD1/, /WORD3/ s/WORD2/foo/' file.txt`

Comment: The question is not about "replacing `WORD2`" but "replacing the string **between WORD1 and WORD3**"

Comment: Ah yes you're right, thanks! The above will work only if you know the string, I got sidetracked by the example.