# sed - Replace characters between two strings with another string

Tags: bash, sed

I have been using IFTTT (if this then that) to notify me whenever some document gets uploaded on a CMS using RSS feeds, but the link that the CMS puts into the RSS feed has spaces and it interferes with the auto link shortening that IFTTT has. For example:

```
<div><b>Attachments:</b> <a href="http://blah.com/foo/bar/Important Announcement 5.doc">http://blah.com/foo/bar/Important Announcement 5.doc</a><br><a href=""></a></div>
```

gives me this in the IFTTT notifications:

```
Attachments: http://is.gd/abcdef Announcement 5.doc
```

I currently rehost the RSS feed using a bash script because IFTTT can't go through authenticated pages. How can I use sed to remove the spaces between those two string?

Comment: which two strings? please include input-> output example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace a unknown string between two known strings with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed)

Comment: Urlencoding your input will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296536/urlencode-from-a-bash-script

Comment: Thanks for your help! After a bit of fumbling around with IFTTT, I found the option to disable automatic link shortening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this might work:

```
awk -F '"' '{OFS="'"'"'"; gsub(" ", "%20", $2); print $0}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! After a bit of fumbling around with IFTTT, I found the option to disable automatic link shortening.