# add dot between known string and unknown string with sed

Tags: regex, sed

Ok, so I know there is a similar post that I referred to already but does not fit the exact issue I am having.

For reference:
[shell sed - substitute an unknown string between a known string and a generic delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055862/shell-sed-substitute-an-unknown-string-between-a-known-string-and-a-generic-de)
[replace a unknown string between two known strings with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed)

`file unknown-string,unknown-string,unknown-string`

i need to add `.` to be like that:

`file unknown-string,.unknown-string,.unknown-string`

i tried `sed -i 's/file.*,/file ,./g' file.txt` not working!

**NOTE: there are many `,` in the file so i can't use sed -i 's/,/,./'**

Thanks.

Comment: `sed 's/,/,./g'`??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,

sorry i forget something, I added  NOTE to the question, that 

NOTE: there are many , in the file so i can't use sed -i 's/,/,./g'

Comment: Okay, that presents a problem. If you don't know what the text is and you can't key off the delimiters because you only want append a `'.'` after some of the delimiters -- that's not much to go on. Do you only want to append the `'.'` after the first and second commas?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,

Yes

Comment: `sed 's/,/,./; s/,/,./'` will work for you then?

Comment: Or `sed -e 's/,/,./1' -e 's/,/,./2'` or just `sed 's/,/,./1;s/,/,./2'` (same thing)

Comment: @Sundeep @DavidC.Rankin,

As i said there are many of `,` in the file, if i tried to use your command, that will add dot to all `,` in the file, i want in this line and others like it when the `file` is known string and `unknown-string,` , i hope you understand me.

Comment: `sed '/^file/s/,/,./1;s/,/,./2'` That will only place a `'.'` after the first two commas in lines that begin with `"file ..."`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,

it's working, but the result is `file unknown-string,unknown-string,.unknown-string` you miss `.` after the first `,`

Comment: I'm a bit confused, testing with `"file unknown-string,unknown-string,unknown-string,unknown-string"` results in `"file unknown-string,.unknown-string,.unknown-string,unknown-string"` -- I thought you only wanted the `'.'` after the first two commas? (make sure you are using the revised version with `.../1.../2` not `.../2 .../3`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,

Yes,i want `.` after the first two commas, but you miss the first comma!

Comment: When i run your command the result will be:

```file unknown-string,unknown-string,.unknown-string```

Comment: there are no `.` after the first comma!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,

Sorry i missing something, now it's working, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,

If you can please post an answer so i can accept it and close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some difficulty understanding the format you were trying to match, to match a line format of:

```
file a,b,c,d....
```

and append a period `'.'` after the first two commas only for line beginning with `file`, you can use a `sed` expression of:

```
sed '/^file/s/,/,./1;s/,/,./2'
```

**Explanation**

- `/^file/` matches only lines beginning with the word `"file"`,
- `s/,/,./1` is the general substitution form where the *find* expression matches a comma `','` and *replaces* it with `",."` with the `1` ending the substitution specifying that the first-occurrence of the match is to be substituted,
- `s/,/,./2` is the same but with `2` specifying that the second-occurrence of the match be replaced.

**Example Use/Output**

Continuing with the format above, you could do:

```
$ echo "file a,b,c,d...." | sed '/^file/s/,/,./1;s/,/,./2'
file a,.b,.c,d....
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.