# How do you convert a mailto link containing a bracketed full name to one without one?

Tags: regex, sed

I am running GNOME 3 and am trying to write a script in a desktop file that redirects mailto links to Yahoo! webmail.

Stuff like [these](http://www.theunixschool.com/2014/08/sed-examples-remove-delete-chars-from-line-file.html) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed) helped me a bit, but I still cannot get a working script.

My goal is to get something like `"mailto:Dan Hoang <ntg255@gmail.com>"` to become `"mailto:ntg255@gmail.com"` and pass it on to Epiphany.

Script so far:

```
Exec=env qs='echo $1 | sed 's/mailto:/To=/' | sed -e 's/\(To==1&\).*\( *@=2&\)/\1\2/' | sed 's/\?subject=/\&Subject=/'' epiphany %U --new-tab http://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?$qs&#8221;
```

Notes:
Script works for mailto links with only e-mail addresses without the `sed -e 's/\(To==1&\).*\( *@=2&\)/\1\2/'` part. This part was my attempt at removing the name.
Also, the %U attached to epiphany serves no purpose; it is only there to allow it to be set as a default application.

Comment: You don't need to run `sed` repeatedly. Just give multiple `-e` options so it performs all the operations.

Comment: You're using the same quote delmiter around the argument to `sed` as you are around the entire `qs=` parameter. That probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This would do:

```
echo "mailto:Dan Hoang <ntg255@gmail.com>" | awk '/mailto:/{gsub(/[<>]/,"");$0="mailto:"$NF}1'
mailto:ntg255@gmail.com
```

Another solution:

```
echo "mailto:Dan Hoang <ntg255@gmail.com>" | awk -F"mailto" 'NF>1{split($2,a,"<|>");$0=FS a[2]}1'
mailtontg255@gmai
```

l.com