# Multiple lazy string replacing between two patterns with sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

Example:

```
This (word1) is a test (word2) file.
```

What I want:

```
This is a test file.
```

The problem is that the brackets occur more than once, so if I use:

```
sed 's/<.*>//g'
```

I get `This file` which it's wrong.

---

How about if I want to replace the string between two same patterns?

Like:

```
WORD1 %WORD2% WORD3 => WORD1 WORD3
```

Comment: so you want to remove all text inside parentheses?

Comment: Exactly. But the parentheses are just a very simple example, it could also be more than one symbol like #/to be replaced/# or %to be replaced%

Comment: Please update the question providing more details.

Comment: @Lobby2: Again, why *same patterns*? Where are the identical parts? What do you expect as an output for `WORD1 %WORD2% WORD3 something WORD1 %WORD2% WORD3`?

Comment: The nominated duplicate specifically answers that case (too).  Please review existing questions before posting here.  Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee: Not all of those answers work with BRE regex. In BRE, there is no `+` support. No lazy quantifiers. And the update is still a bit unclear now.

Comment: Adding a BRE answer to the (wannabe) canonical question would be a very welcome addition indeed.  However, because the [regex] tag is so full of gunk, it's hard to point to a single preferred canonical question.  If you can point to a better duplicate, you can do that -- flag for moderator attention to redirect the duplicate notice.

Comment: I have just found out that `\+` works, so it is not pure BRE. Here is a potentially [another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed).

Comment: @stribizhev That's an excellent one!  Now just leave it to OP to decide which one to upvote (or maybe both).

Comment: @stribizhev: WORD1 WORD3 as output. But I find out that also works with sed 's/%[^%%]*%//g'

Comment: There is no need repeating `%` inside the character class. A `[...]` construct only matches 1 single character from the set specified inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is a negated character class `[^<>]*` that will match any character but a `<` or `>`:

```
sed 's/<[^<>]*>//g'
```

Or, if you have round brackets you can use `[^()]*` (note that in BRE syntax, to match a literal `(` or `)` escaping `\` is not necessary):

```
sed 's/([^()]*)//g'
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/KTqry4)

As for the update, you can remove everything from `WORD1` till `WORD3` using `.*`, but *only if there is only one set of `WORD1` and `WORD3`* ([demo](http://ideone.com/gAujaN)):

```
echo "WORD1 %WORD2% WORD3" | sed 's/WORD1.*WORD3/WORD1 WORD3/g'
```

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), it is not possible to use lookarounds (lookaheads here), nor lazy quantifiers to restrict the match to the leftmost `WORD3` occurrences. And if you know for sure there is no `%` symbol in between, you can still use the negated character class approach ([demo](http://ideone.com/VNItCk)):

```
echo "WORD1 %WORD2% WORD3" | sed 's/%[^%]*%//g'
```

**A generic solution** is to do it in several steps:

- replace the starting and ending delimiters with **unused character** (`<UC>`) (I am using Russian letters, but it should be some control character)
- use the negated character class `<UC1>[^<UC1><UC2>]*<UC2>` to replace with the necessary replacement string
- restore the initial delimiters.

Here is an [example](http://ideone.com/ihJNgw):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "WORD1 %WORD2% WORD3 some text WORD1 %WORD2% WORD3" | 
  sed 's/WORD1/й/g' |
  sed 's/WORD3/ч/g' |
  sed 's/й[^йч]*ч/й ч/g' |
  sed 's/й/WORD1/g' |
  sed 's/ч/WORD3/g' 
 // => WORD1 WORD3 some text WORD1 WORD3
```

I am hardcoding a space, but it can be adjusted whenever necessary.

Comment: Now I have another problem: how about if I wanna replace the string between two same patterns? Like WORD1 %WORD2% WORD3 => WORD1 WORD3?

Comment: These are not the same if you mean you have known `WORD1` and `WORD3` and you need to remove all between them. Maybe you need [this](http://ideone.com/arFuZx).

Comment: This is a very common question.  Please refrain from answering if you do not have the time to hunt down a good duplicate.

Comment: You have a gold badge in the regex tag.  Your answer contains no lookarounds.

Comment: If you are referring to the OP's follow-up question; no, I am ignoring that.  If the OP has a new question, they should post a new question, or edit the current question.

Comment: @triplee: sorry I´m just new here, now I know to update the question :P