# bash regex not working

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

So I have this code

```
function test(){
  local output="ASD[test]"
  if [[ "$output" =~ ASD\[(.*?)\] ]]; then
     echo "success";
  else
     echo "fail"
  fi;
}
```

And as you can see it's supposed to echo success since the string matches that regular expression. However this ends up returning fail. What did I do wrong?

Comment: In your if condition shoudnt that $output be without quotes

Comment: @Manish tried that didnt work

Comment: check this :- http://ideone.com/c1ojBS

its working

Comment: Yes it won't work because your regular expression is also not correct. What you actually want?

Comment: @Manish regex is correct as well as code is running..don't understand OP's problem

Comment: it's seriously not working on my bash...I'm using version 4.1.17(0)-release

Comment: @rock321987 i m not saying that regex is wrong but it won't match the value of $output. U got my point right.

Comment: @Manish why isn't it matching....this guy says it matches: http://regexr.com/3d9i4

Comment: can you show your terminal output

Comment: the terminal simply outputs "fail" ... nothing more nothing less, i've tried restarting bash, rerunning "source .bashrc" etc

Comment: how its possible..its working everywhere..though the version of bash i am using is `4.3.11`

Comment: not sure if it matters but I'm also using the built in bash in this guy: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

Comment: @rock321987 try using the mobaxterm terminal in that mobaxterm.mobatek.net link

Comment: i think the problem can be with `\\`` because windows uses it in its path..try matching only `ASD`

Comment: is there any online version of that available or I need to install it?

Comment: @rock321987 you'll need to install it

Comment: You should rename your function `test()` not to confuse with the `test` shell builtin.

Comment: You need to escape `?` try `ASD\[.*\\?\]`..i am searching for its reason

Comment: I found that bash does not supports lazy match using `.*?`.  So you have to use alternative approach suggested in other answer

Comment: Here, the solution is easy. If the delimiters were not single but multiple characters, I'd recommend [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311692/multiple-lazy-string-replacing-between-two-patterns-with-sed/34311727#34311727).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` in `ASD\[(.*?)\]` doesn't belong there.  It looks like you're trying to apply a non-greedy modifier to the `*`, which is `*?` in Perl-compatible syntax, but Bash doesn't support that. (See the guide [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns).) In fact, if you examine `$?` after the test, you'll see that it's not 1 (the normal "string didn't match" result) but 2, which indicates a syntax error in the regular expression.

If you use the simpler pattern `ASD\[(.*)\]`, then the match will succeed. However, if you use that regex on a string which might have later instances of brackets, too much will get captured by the parentheses. For example:

```
output=ASD[test1],ASD[test2]
[[ $output =~ ASD\[(.*)\] ]] && echo "first subscript is '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}'"
#=> first subscript is 'test1],ASD[test2'
```

In languages that support the `*?` syntax, it makes the matching "non-greedy" so that it will match the smallest string it can that makes the overall match succeed; without the `?`, such expressions always match the longest possible instead. Since Bash doesn't have non-greediness, your best bet is probably to use a character class that matches everything *except* a close bracket, making it impossible for the match to move past the first one:

```
[[ $output =~ ASD\[([^]]*)\] ]] && echo "first subscript is '${BASH_REMATCH[1]}'"
#=> first subscript is 'test1'
```

Note that this breaks if there are any nested layers of bracket pairs within the subscript brackets - but then, so does the `*?` version.