# Regular Expressions ungreedy in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, expression

Choose which of the following strings match regular expression

```
(1 U 22)*2*

a. 22112222112211
b. 11112
c. The empty string.
d. 12121
e. 1121111222
```

I did a few search, U means " Ungreedy. Makes the quantifiers *+?{} consume only those characters absolutely necessary to form a match, leaving the remaining ones available for the next part of the pattern. When the "U" option is not in effect, an individual quantifier can be made non-greedy by following it with a question mark. Conversely, when "U" is in effect, the question mark makes an individual quantifier greedy. "   https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

but I totally don't understand it, what does greedy regular expression and ungreedy regular expression mean? and can you show the example that I listed above?

Comment: use https://regex101.com/ to visualize what is happening in debugger mode

Comment: Greedy matches the longest matching string. Ungreedy matches the shortest.

Comment: @rock321987 no that's not duplicate question, all I want to know is how to use the option `U` here with regular expression and understand what is ungreedy

Comment: @123 could you provide some simple example to demonstrate that? Sorry I am very new to linux....

Comment: How is AutoHotkey related to bash?

Comment: @linux There is a simple example in the duplicate.

Comment: @choroba I changed to another reference , it does for bash

Comment: Bash doesn't support `\Q` and frugal quantifiers.

Comment: *but I totally don't understand it, what does greedy regular expression and ungreedy regular expression mean?* makes this question a dupe. If you want to know how to use lazy matching in Linux, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34311727/3832970).

Answer (score -1):

Greedy means that it will try to find the longest matching string.

For the following string:

```
{ this} is a { test} }
```

**Example of a Greedy regex**

`\{.*\}`

This regex would match the whole following text:

{ this} is a { test} }

**Non Greedy**

`\{.*\}`

would match only
`{ this}`

Comment: Where's `?`: `\{.*?\}`?