# How to add text inside brackets after certain pattern keeping the original text

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, latex

I have a latex file in which I would like to replace the content inside a \caption environment.

In particular, I want to use bold text and change the size. As an example:

```
%ORIGINAL
\caption{ Some text }
%...
\env2{ \caption{ Other text } }
```

to something like this

```
%NEW FILE
\caption{ \scriptsize\textbf{ Some text } }
%...
\env2 { \caption {\scriptsize\textbf{ Other text } } }
```

I am able to use sed to extract the text between the two patterns "\caption{" and the closing "}" as shown in this question: [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

And I am as well able to replace the inner text with a known string, as shown here : [replace a unknown string between two known strings with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed)

My question is: how do I keep the unknown strings inside the newly added environment, just using a single sed command and replacing only the surrounding strings ? Maybe something like:

```
START-PATTERN [new-environments] [Inner-text] [closing-brackets] END-PATTERN
```

Thank you.

Comment: This has the potential to go horribly wrong if the caption contains an escaped `}` or goes onto multiple lines...

Comment: You are right, indeed I am having problems especially in the case of complex multiline text. I don't know if a simple solution may be found.

Comment: A better solution would be to change the style of your `\caption` environment. I'd recommend looking at how to do that. There's an example of something related here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/822/50142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sed**

This is a `sed` oneliner that works for monoline blocks handling escaped curly brackets (`\{` or `\}`) **correctly**:

```
 sed -r 's/\\caption[ \t]*\{(([^\{}]|\\.)*)\}/\\caption\{\\scriptsize\\textbf\{\1\}\}/g' input.file
```

The *per-line edit* nature of `sed` does not allow this to work on multiline blocks.

**Perl**

To avoid this limitation you can use the same regex with `perl` (enabling `slurp mode` in the `BEGIN` block):

```
# Note double backslash \\ inside [...], not required in sed
perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/\\caption[ \t]*\{(([^\\{}]|\\.)*)\}/\\caption\{\\scriptsize\\textbf\{\1\}\}/g' input.file
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH5cR1/1)

**Input**

```
%ORIGINAL
\caption{ \{Some text\}
    some other \{text\}
}
%...
\env2{ \caption{ Other text } }
```

**Output**

```
%ORIGINAL
\caption{\scriptsize\textbf{ \{Some text\}
    some other \{text\}
}}
%...
\env2{ \caption{\scriptsize\textbf{ Other text }} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes the sed for your example.

`sed 's/\\caption\s*{\([^}]*\)}/ \\caption {\\scriptsize\\textbf{ \1 } }/g'`

Change it according to your need.

Explanation:

`\\caption\s*{\([^}]*\)}`

- \\ matches the character \ literally
- caption matches the characters caption literally
- \s* match any white space character between zero and unlimited times
- { matches the character { literally
- ([^}]*) get everything until find } ,obs: capturing group
- } matches the character } literally

`\\caption {\\scriptsize\\textbf{ \1 } }`

Replace the matched text by the text above, and put inside \textbf() the first group information matched (for example: some text or other text)