# Replace javascript code between two patterns using bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following code:

```
    this.directives.forEach(function (dir) {
        var myVar = "hello";
        if (control.text !== myVar) {
            cleanUp(control);
            if (dir)
                setUpControl(myVar, dir);
            control = dir;
        }
    });
```

And need to replace everything that is between: `if (control !== myVar) {` and `}`. I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed) and tried the following:

```
sed -i 's/(if \(control\.text !== myVar\) \{).*?(\})/\1 REPLACEMENT_STRING \2/is' myFile.js
```

which returns

```
sed: 1: "s/(if \(control\.text ! ...": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)
```

Comment: `\{` is opening repetition but then you follow it with a `(` which is not a valid argument, should be like `{n,m}`. You want a literal `{` which you should not escape. Even fixing that though your command won't work since sed edits line by line.

Comment: @123 what would you recommend to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one but it's not really efficient if some '{' appear in your function...

```
sed '/if (control\.text !== myVar) {/!b;p;s/.*/REPLACEMENT_STRING/p;:A;N;/}/!{s/.*//;bA};D' myFile.js
```

Comment: Seems to work but my replacement string messes everything up. My whole sed is: `sed -i '/if (dir\._control !== newCtrl) {/!b;p;s/.*/\t\t\t\tcleanUpControl(dir\._control, dir);\n\t\t\t\tif (newCtrl \&\& newCtrl instanceof FormControl) {\n\t\t\t\t\tsetUpControl(newCtrl, dir);\n\t\t\t\t\tdir\._control = newCtrl;\n\t\t\t\t} else {\n\t\t\t\t\tdir\._control = null;\n\t\t\t\t}/p;:A;N;/}/!{s/.*//;bA};D' forms.umd.js` but it copies twice what I need and doesn't replace but add. any idea?