# find a word between two words in unix shell scripting

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a file(sample.txt) with below content in the unix server.

```
--password xyzabcdef --username
```

I want to find the text `xyzabcdef` and replace it with `xxxxxxxxx` using `sed`. `xyzabcdef` is just a sample text, everytime the text and length of the text can change, and hence no hardcoding of the text.

Note: `--password --username` text is standard and wont change. I just want to find the text between these two and replace it.

expected result

```
--password xxxxxxxxx --username
```

Comment: On SO we encourage users to post their efforts in their question, so kindly do so and let us know then

Comment: I think this answer suits better. Thanks though!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613643/replace-a-unknown-string-between-two-known-strings-with-sed